# Filtering Dataframe date and time wise

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Timestamp   Maximum Demand  Consumption
3/1/2017 6:00   116 116
3/1/2017 7:00   1532    118
3/1/2017 8:00   2008    119
3/1/2017 9:00   3008    125
3/1/2017 10:00  4472    122
3/1/2017 11:00  4964    123
3/1/2017 12:00  5908    118
3/1/2017 13:00  7324    118
3/1/2017 14:00  7800    119
3/1/2017 15:00  8752    119
3/1/2017 16:00  10216   122
3/1/2017 17:00  10716   125
3/1/2017 18:00  11676   120
3/1/2017 19:00  13164   124
3/1/2017 20:00  13628   116
3/1/2017 21:00  14572   118
3/1/2017 22:00  16048   123
3/1/2017 23:00  16540   123
4/1/2017 0:00   17476   117
4/1/2017 1:00   18916   120
4/1/2017 2:00   19384   117
4/1/2017 3:00   20312   116
4/1/2017 4:00   21764   121
4/1/2017 5:00   22228   116
4/1/2017 6:00   23204   122
4/1/2017 7:00   24704   125
4/1/2017 8:00   25204   125
4/1/2017 9:00   26172   121
4/1/2017 10:00  27552   115
4/1/2017 11:00  28028   119
4/1/2017 12:00  28988   120
4/1/2017 13:00  30488   125
4/1/2017 14:00  30960   118
4/1/2017 15:00  31920   120
4/1/2017 16:00  33408   124
4/1/2017 17:00  33904   124
4/1/2017 18:00  34880   122

Date format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
```

I am trying to Filter data on the basis of time and date.

example: From time `(07:00 - 18:00)`, `(19:00 - 22:00)` and `(23:00 - 06:00)`
Expected Output:

```
3/1/2017 7:00   1532    118
3/1/2017 8:00   2008    119
3/1/2017 9:00   3008    125
3/1/2017 10:00  4472    122
3/1/2017 11:00  4964    123
3/1/2017 12:00  5908    118
3/1/2017 13:00  7324    118
3/1/2017 14:00  7800    119
3/1/2017 15:00  8752    119
3/1/2017 16:00  10216   122
3/1/2017 17:00  10716   125
3/1/2017 18:00  11676   120
```

I am a beginner and I am confused. How can I achieve this?
Please help.

I tried this in my code:

```
offpeak = df2[(df2.index.hour == 6) & (df2.index.minute == 0)]
normal = df2[(df2.index.hour == 18) & (df2.index.minute == 0)]
peak = df2[(df2.index.hour == 22) & (df2.index.minute == 0)]
```

Comment: what exact output do you want?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, Thanks for replying. I want the data of the mentioned time. Like the data between (07:00 - 18:00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), but first convert column `Timestamp` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then set index from it:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True)

df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
offpeak  = df.between_time('7:00', '18:00')
normal = df.between_time('19:00', '22:00')
peak = df.between_time('23:00', '6:00')
```

---

```
print (offpeak)
                     Maximum Demand  Consumption
Timestamp                                       
2017-01-03 07:00:00            1532          118
2017-01-03 08:00:00            2008          119
2017-01-03 09:00:00            3008          125
2017-01-03 10:00:00            4472          122
2017-01-03 11:00:00            4964          123
2017-01-03 12:00:00            5908          118
2017-01-03 13:00:00            7324          118
2017-01-03 14:00:00            7800          119
2017-01-03 15:00:00            8752          119
2017-01-03 16:00:00           10216          122
2017-01-03 17:00:00           10716          125
2017-01-03 18:00:00           11676          120
2017-01-04 07:00:00           24704          125
2017-01-04 08:00:00           25204          125
2017-01-04 09:00:00           26172          121
2017-01-04 10:00:00           27552          115
2017-01-04 11:00:00           28028          119
2017-01-04 12:00:00           28988          120
2017-01-04 13:00:00           30488          125
2017-01-04 14:00:00           30960          118
2017-01-04 15:00:00           31920          120
2017-01-04 16:00:00           33408          124
2017-01-04 17:00:00           33904          124
2017-01-04 18:00:00           34880          122
```

If need also filter by `date`:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True)
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
offpeak  = df['2017-01-04'].between_time('7:00', '18:00')
print (offpeak)
                     Maximum Demand  Consumption
Timestamp                                       
2017-01-04 07:00:00           24704          125
2017-01-04 08:00:00           25204          125
2017-01-04 09:00:00           26172          121
2017-01-04 10:00:00           27552          115
2017-01-04 11:00:00           28028          119
2017-01-04 12:00:00           28988          120
2017-01-04 13:00:00           30488          125
2017-01-04 14:00:00           30960          118
2017-01-04 15:00:00           31920          120
2017-01-04 16:00:00           33408          124
2017-01-04 17:00:00           33904          124
2017-01-04 18:00:00           34880          122
```

Comment: Thanks. can i filter this output on dates as well?

Comment: What if i dont know the date? Like the data can be of any date right?

Comment: Ok.Thank You. :)

Comment: sure, only small bug - need `dayfirst` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for correct parsinf dates, check edited answer.